# Does Google Analytics collect any information about the contents of the web page?

Tags: web-application, javascript, confidentiality

If I enable Google Analytics on my web application, does the Google Analytics Javascript collect any information on the web page (any of the content on the page)?  Does it collect any information about the GET parameters in the URL or the POST parameters for the page?

I've done a lot of Googling and found a lot of references indicating that Google Analytics collects information about the browser and operating system version, screen resolution, IP address, etc., stuff like that.  However, I'm wondering if it collects any information about the contents of the page that the server sends to the user, since some of the information in the page is confidential and not something that I want Google to collect.  Similarly for some of the GET/POST parameters.

---

I haven't found a good unobfuscated version of the ga.js Javascript file that Google Analytics loads, but here's one unminified version that I found: http://blog.xam.de/2008/07/towards-gajs-un-obfuscated.html#!/2008/07/towards-gajs-un-obfuscated.html

Answer (score 2):

You can install the [Google Analytics Debugger Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) to see the data that is getting sent to Google. I don't believe that it sends any of the page content, other than the page's title and URL (including GET parameters).